# Designing band-stop filter (at SciPy firwin)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am trying to design a bunch of filters for my data using the kaiserord window with `firwin`. I have managed to create a low-pass filter and a band-pass filter based on the information provided across the internet. However, I can't create neither a band-stop filter nor a high-pass filter. I am using the pass_zero input from firwin to choose if the filter is either a band-pass/low-pass filter or a band-stop/high-pass filter ([as indicated in firwin documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html))

I am using the following code for the high-pass filter:

```
from scipy.signal import kaiserord, firwin, freqz
from pylab import figure, clf, plot, xlabel, ylabel, xlim, ylim, title, grid, axes, show

# The Nyquist rate of the signal.
nyq_rate = sample_rate / 2.0

# The desired width of the transition from pass to stop,
# relative to the Nyquist rate.
width = 5/nyq_rate

# The desired attenuation in the stop band, in dB.
ripple_db = 60.0

# Compute the order and Kaiser parameter for the FIR filter.
N, beta = kaiserord(ripple_db, width)
print('Filter order: ', N)

# Use firwin with a Kaiser window to create the high-pass FIR filter.
taps = firwin(N, 15/nyq_rate, window=('kaiser', beta), pass_zero=False)

figure(1)
clf()
w, h = freqz(taps, worN=8000)
plot((w/pi)*nyq_rate, absolute(h), linewidth=2)
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Gain')
title('Frequency Response')
ylim(-0.05, 1.05)
grid(True)
```

This throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\DT\Miniconda3\envs\cmoenv\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\fir_filter_design.py", line 409, in firwin
    raise ValueError("A filter with an even number of coefficients must "
ValueError: A filter with an even number of coefficients must have zero response at the Nyquist frequency.
```

Can, please, someone help me designing the high-pass and band-stop filters using kaiserord?

Many thanks!
DT

Comment: Before calling `firwin`, add the statement `N |= 1`.  This will ensure that `N` is odd.  (The statement is equivalent to `N = N | 1`, and `|` is the bitwise `or` operator.  The statement sets the lowest bit of `N` to 1.)

Comment: A longer way of writing that statement is with an `if`, for example `if N % 2 == 0: N = N + 1`.  That how it was done in a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291164/how-to-implement-a-fir-high-pass-filter-in-python

Comment: Awesome @WarrenWeckesser! That indeed works :). But why do I need to do that, actually? (Perhaps post your answer as an answer, so that I can mark it right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling `firwin`, add the statement

```
N |= 1
```

This will ensure that N is odd. The statement is equivalent to N = N | 1, and | is the bitwise or operator. The statement sets the lowest bit of N to 1.

Quoting from the docstring of the function,

> This function computes the coefficients of a finite impulse response filter. The filter will have linear phase; it will be Type I if `numtaps` is odd and Type II if `numtaps` is even.
>
> Type II filters always have zero response at the Nyquist frequency, so a ValueError exception is raised if firwin is called with `numtaps` even and having a passband whose right end is at the Nyquist frequency.

To put it another way: the array of coefficients returned by `firwin` always has even symmetry, and mathematically, a filter with even symmetry and an even number of taps will automatically have zero response at the Nyquist frequency, so it does not make sense to design a high-pass or band-stop filter with `firwin` that has an even number of taps.

Take a look at this Q&A for more background on FIR filter types: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9408/fir-filter-with-linear-phase-4-types